# Effect of base doping on early voltage,base transport factor and emitter injection efficiency?

Tags: transistors, bjt, homework

[image]

---

According to me as base doping increases recombination will be less at base region so **base transport factor** and **emitter injection efficiency** will **increase** and as effective base width will decrease due to less doping at the base region so **early voltage will decrease.**
am I thinking right? No options is matching.

Comment: Why does MORE base doping reduce the base recombination?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a typing error in your analysis,
"*According to me as base doping* **increases** *...*"
Here, it should be **decreases** and rest are fine;

And yes your conclusion is right ,
i.e,
$$ \text{as } \quad  N_B \downarrow \quad \to \quad \gamma \text{ (Emitter Injection Efficiency) } \uparrow  \quad, \quad \beta^{*} \,\, \uparrow \,\,\& \,\,|V_A| \,\,\downarrow $$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lower base doping:
Increase emitter injection efficiency (ratio of emitter:base doping)

Increase base transport factor as lower doping means less recombination for minority carriers injected from the emitter

Increase early voltage - because the base-collector junction depletion region will deplete more into the collector than the base- therefor the base edge of the depletion region will not reduce the overall base width as much.